# UIScrollView - How to position controls

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview, interface-builder

I am pretty confused on how to position the controls on a UIScrollView  that extends beyond the associated UIView.

I have a long form that needs to be filled out which is on one long UIScrollView.  I have read (but can't believe) that there is no way to use InterfaceBuilder in order to position the controls, but instead you have to hardcode X\Y coords. in code (or in IB, but they still won't show as WYSIWIG)

Do you really have to do this all with hard coded coords ?

If so what is the best approach to accomplish this ?  What if certain controls can become "hidden"...do you then need to have code that moves the coordinates of all controls further down on the page up ?

Would a better approach be to put all the controls on different views and then add those views to the UIScrollView (at least you could then "see" them in IB...)

I hope I am missing something :-)

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to do all of this in code.

You can just have an XIB file for your embedded UIView. This can be as large as you need it to be. Then have a view controller that loads this XIB, and add its view to your scroll view (setting the content size appropriately.)

As for hiding controls - XIB files probably won't help you there. But you can hide controls and adjust the coordinates of other controls in code. (And change the content size of your scroll view if necessary.) This might be a reason to have different controls in different subviews of your scroll view's content view.

Answer (score 0):

In IB, you can create your UIScrollView at the top of the hierarchy and give it the height that you want. Then you can set your elements as you want, in a WYSIWYG way. Once you finished, you just set the size of your UIScrollView to the size you want and set it under the hierarchy of your ViewController's UIView, and finally in the code, you set the content size of your UIScrollView to the size it takes. Easy !

I would encourage you to read this http://www.uxbooth.com/blog/mobile-form-design-strategies/, it's good advice if you want to design a long form, in a user friendly way :)